# C# OleDB Delete Command

Tags: c#, database, crud, ole

I am currently creating an window application connected with a Microsoft Access database to perform CRUD operation for the business related to education

One of the workflow is to search the keyword and perform CRUD operation in the DataGrid View
At first , I am trying to display the datagrid view of the record ( such as students , time to take course, what course...e.t.c.)  with respect to the receipt number

The application logic is to get the receipt number in the datagrid View and perform delete operation

So my question is

1. How to get the value of the receipt number column in  the selected row  of the datagrid view?
2. There are OleCommands and OleDataAdapter to perform the CRUD operation. Which method shall I use ?

The following is the code for the delete operation

```
        public void delete_course_transaction(string receipt_no)
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        try
        {

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionDBString))
            {
                string sql = "delete from COURSE_TAKE where COURSE_TAKE.RECEIPT_NO = '" + receipt_no + "'";
                connection.Open();
                oledbAdapter.DeleteCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                oledbAdapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = sql;
                int rows = oledbAdapter.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rows > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Delete Course transaction Success!");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly :

for your first question you can use this code :

```
txtName.Text = dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
```

and your second question :
refer here :http://forums.asp.net/t/706106.aspx/1

Comment: how about returning the name of column in the datagridview when a particular cell is selected

Comment: @LoWaiLun use this code : txtName.Text = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;

Comment: @LoWaiLun in  dataGridView1_CellClick event.