# Is there an equivalent for SQL server's 'output deleted' statement for MS Access?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access

I'm working on a project and I normally use SQL Server but for my class, I have to use MS Access.  I have all my code set up but I keep getting a syntax error when I use the 'OUTPUT Deleted.*' statement in my delete query.  Is there some equivalent for MS access that I'm unaware of? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need?

```
string command = "Delete from table where [ID] = ?";
```

more on [Oledb Delete Command](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/DeletedatabaserecordsthroughOleDbCommandandverifytheresults.htm)

and [C# OleDB Delete Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656140/c-sharp-oledb-delete-command)

Comment: Not quite. If I were to use SQL server, my query would be "string command = "DELETE FROM EmpSys OUTPUT DELETED.resumelink WHERE recordkey = @recordkey" but that won't work for MS Access.

Comment: Nah he's not talking about deleting, he's wanting this `delete from yourtable output deleted.* where ...` in MS Access

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this [OUTPUT DELETE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) from TSQL?

> Returns information from, or expressions based on, each row affected
>   by an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement. These results can be
>   returned to the processing application for use in such things as
>   confirmation messages, archiving, and other such application
>   requirements. The results can also be inserted into a table or table
>   variable. Additionally, you can capture the results of an OUTPUT
>   clause in a nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement, and
>   insert those results into a target table or view.